# When reading a file in emacs, how can I set the "shell" for Shell-script mode?

Tags: shell, emacs

I have some files that are not shell scripts *per se*, but designed to be sourced by shell scripts. Therefore, the file name don't match any pattern in `auto-mode-alist` (nor am I interested in trying to update for each file).

When I edit one of my bash scripts (e.g., **foo.bash**), emacs properly deduces the shell and the mode line shows `Shell-script[bash]`. Whether this is based on filename or shebang line is immaterial, I think. I'd like to force this behavior for my "non-script" script files.

What I came up with was this:

```sh
# -*- mode: Shell-script; eval (sh_set_shell "bash"); -*-
```

But that gives a warning about the `eval` (rightly so). How else can I set the dialect for Shell-script mode?

Comment: This is probably better suited for https://emacs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a file local variables block and set `sh-shell` in addition to the major mode:

```
# Local Variables:
# mode: shell-script
# sh-shell: bash
# End:
```

If you dislike this big (better readable :) ) block, a one liner will do niceley (per @jwm comment below):

```
# -*- mode: Shell-script; sh_shell: "bash"; -*-
```

**Nota Bene:** According to the documentation, using the file-local variable `sh-shell` is equivalent to calling `sh-set-shell`, and the intended way to set this up:

> Shell script files can cause this function be called automatically
> when the file is visited by having a `sh-shell' file-local variable
> whose value is the shell name (don't quote it).

Comment: I ended up poking around the .el file and found the `sh-shell` variable. Is it merely disappointing that it isn't documented in the mode docs, or is there a reason to prefer `(sh_set_shell "bash")` over `(setq 'sh-shell "bash")`?

Comment: also, I ended up with `# -*- mode: Shell-script; sh_shell: "bash"; -*-`. Since I think these are two ways to do the same thing, if you want to put both options in your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: In addition to the readability, I find the former slightly more than the latter, FWIW, b/c my shell-check issues a warning, `On most OS, shebangs can only specify a single parameter.`, thinking that the shebang line is supposed to do something with that emacs-mode declaration.